# WCF Multiple Concurrency Service That is Restricted to Single App Domain

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, appdomain

I have a service that has been running for over a year, and gets hit with 500K - 1 Million requests per day, and handles a decent amount of processing. Typically a request lasts 30-45 seconds. Thus, we have specified for the service to use ConcurrencyMode = Multiple and InstanceContextMode = PerCall. This has worked well for us.

The issue I am running into is that an area of my code uses a singleton pattern to expose a static instance, which I need to guarantee there can only be one copy of. The problem I am running into after troubleshooting is, there are multiple app domains creating multiple instances. This is causing issues. How can I guarantee that only one application domain is created for a service?

Answer (score 2):

not directly answering the question: *How can I guarantee that only one application domain is created for a service?*,

How about decoupling this 'singleton' component of yours in a separate process entirely, out of IIS, say as a windows service and consume its services over WCF-Named-Pipe binding? I have used named-pipe+WCF+win-service, and found the communication framework heavily optimized for performance. all the ram/cpu cost is of the code running in the singleton service methods.

Of course if the singleton-service-provider needs to be memory-joint to the actual service code then it could be a problem. still an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking code-wise, might be worth looking up Jon Skeets Singleton solutions [here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

However if you are running multiple instances of the entire program, you've got no choice but to extract out your singleton calls to a windows service, web service or database call.